# What are the triangle free graphs on $\lfloor\frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor$ edges .

Tags: graph-theory

I tried for $n=4$, it is a cycle of length $4$ which is $K_{2,2}$. $n=5$, it seems to be $K_{2,3}$. So my guess is it is a complete bipartite graph?

Comment: That's a strong conjecture on slim evidence. Did you try $n=6$?

Comment: $K_{3,3}$ has 9 edges

Comment: A bipartite graph is triangle-free, so it's easy to find complete bipartite graphs that satisfy the requirement.  The difficulty would be in showing these are the only examples (if that's true.)

Comment: I went through the graph on 6 vertices on this link: http://graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html#nodes6  and did not find any . I don't know if the list is complete as I didn't find $k_{3,3}$. I couldn't find a good one for 7 vertices either.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial case of [Turán’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem) for $r=2$. The unique (up to a isomorphism) edge-maximal triangle-free graph is a Turán graph, which is a complete bipartite graph on $n$ vertices such that the sizes of the parts differs by at most one.